# Android camera2 tap to focus

Tags: android, camera, camera2

Trying to implement tap to `focus` using `camera2api`.

```
    CaptureRequest.Builder afBuilder = mPreviewBuilder;

    Rect newRect=new Rect(0,0,200,200);
    MeteringRectangle meteringRectangle=new MeteringRectangle(newRect,METERING_WEIGHT_DONT_CARE);

    MeteringRectangle[] areas = afBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS);

    mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS,areas);
    mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
    mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
    mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

In my call back I am continuously getting stuck in an `ACTIVE_SCAN` state and occasionally goes into `FOCUS_NOT_LOCKED` state. I can never seem to get into a `FOCUS_LOCKED` state and the preview never look focused.

Using a samsung galaxy note 3.

Comment: I'm fetching `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rect.left must be nonnegative`. could you please guide me!

Comment: Might be worth starting a new question on this. Do you have any more information on the issue, code sample etc.?

Comment: Solved using `SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE`. I had mixed old Camera code with new `Camera2` `MeteringRectangle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you're not actually setting an AF region - you're just reusing the default region from mPreviewBuilder.

Second, even if you set the region to [(0,0,200,200), METERING_WEIGHT_DONT_CARE], that's the top-left corner of the image, and probably not what you want?

Third, and most importantly, you're setting the AF trigger to be repeating.  This means that on every frame, you're asking the camera to restart focusing. So it will never complete, because you never let it.

You need to set AF_TRIGGER to START for only a single capture; you'll still want to set the AF_REGION and AF_MODE on repeating request to be consistent through the whole AF scan you're starting.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the rectangles were more of an example for this post.

I will try sorting the trigger though, this is for recording video app just to put it into some context.

Comment: Thank you so much it was the repeating trigger issue!

Comment: @YRfreeDevelopers could you kindly update the OP with the code of the fix?

Comment: @Eddy Talvala, So i can't set the region manually using coordinates?